# Compute Count for multiple values in one query

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I have a table of answers like this:

```
ID ItemID Answer 
1   1      yes
2   1      no
3   1      yes
4   1      yes
5   2      no
6   2      yes
7   3      yes
```

I'd like to be able to provide an array of `ItemId` and compute the `number of yes answers - number of no answers` for each `ItemID` in the array.

I can do this for an individual item like this:

`SELECT (SELECT count(ID) FROM table WHERE ItemID= <id> AND Answer = 'Yes') - (SELECT count(ID) FROM table WHERE ItemID= <id> AND Answer = 'No') AS difference`

but how can I adapt this to work for multiple ids in one query?

My expected output, given the input `[1,2]` would look like

```
ItemID Difference 
  1      2
  2      0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregatoin:

```
select itemid,
       count(*) filter (where answer = 'yes') as num_yes,
       count(*) filter (where answer = 'no') as num_no
from t
group by itemid;
```

You can include `where itemid in (1, 2)` (or something similar) if you want to limit this to particular items.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve with below mentioned query using case statement and aggregation:

try this

```
select itemid "ItemID", sum(case when answer = 'yes' then 1 else -1 end) "Difference"
from example 
where itemid in (1,2) --condition can be removed if required for all IDs
group by itemid
```

[**Demo**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oscoX5E9oXDuhSk1sdgMgE/0)